# How can I detect video file duration in minutes with PHP?

Tags: php, video

I am trying to detect the duration of any video file before it is uploaded with PHP
so if it is less than one minute for example I will refuse uploading it.
if it is not possible , how can I do it after uploading the video ??

Comment: Sorry there is none .. you need to upload the file first :D

Comment: @Baba and how can I do it after uploading the file?

Comment: Hm not really sure about videos but for audio it works. Try getID3 http://getid3.sourceforge.net/. There are some classes which can be used to get basic video data.

Comment: There are ways to detect the file size before uploading , if you use flash based uploaders. May work for you if u think just making a thorough guess would work for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get video duration, dimension and size in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get `video duration` with `ffmpeg`  or getID3

Example

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);
echo("Duration: ".$file['playtime_string'].
        " / Dimensions: ".$file['video']['resolution_x']." wide by ".$file['video']['resolution_y']." tall".
        " / Filesize: ".$file['filesize']." bytes<br />");
```

Or

```
 ob_start();
 passthru("ffmpeg -i working_copy.flv  2>&1");
 $duration = ob_get_contents();
 $full = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 $search = "/duration.*?([0-9]{1,})/";
 print_r($duration);
 $duration = preg_match($search, $duration, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
 print_r('<pre>');
 print_r($matches[1][0]);
 print_r($full);
```

Please see

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

http://ffmpeg.org/

[How to get video duration, dimension and size in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847752/how-to-get-video-duration-dimension-and-size-in-php)

[get flv video length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214924/get-flv-video-length)

Thanks

:D

Comment: he is saying he needs this before uploading. Thanks :D

Comment: See his comment `@Baba and how can I do it after uploading the file? – Ayman Jitan 6 mins ago` @kommradHomer

Comment: wow. i've to read every comment before commenting for not being ashamed

Comment: @kommradHomer , if I can do it before uploading that will be great :)

Comment: you can just make a wide guess , by using a flash-based uploader to check the file size before uploading. Actually , if u try to avoid having small files , then whats the problem ? let them load small files , its not a big burden. it would be a burden if u were trying to run away from big files, as thats what we usually do.

Comment: What is the essence of duration before upload ...  kommradHomer  has a valid point

Answer (score 0):

for people coming to check this out this is a solution a little more advanced for the year 2017

```
     first download the latest version from the first link above in the accepted answer the (green checkmark)          

     require_once('getid/getid3/getid3.php'); //path to your get id file if you do not include this in your file it will result in an error meaning the code will not work
$file = "sade.mp4"; //what you want extract info from maybe mp3,or mp4 file anything you want to get file size in bytes or time duration
$uuuuu = "videos/"; //path to your video file it could also be music not only video
$getID3 = new getID3; //initialize engine
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($uuuuu.$file);
getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities(print_r($ThisFileInfo, true)).'</pre>';  //use this to print array to pick whatever you like that you want value like playduration, filesize
```